# CKEditor disable all text styles

Tags: jquery, css, ckeditor

I have a form where users enter their messages in CKEditor and can change font color and other things. Also there's a second form for viewing messages which are stored in Database.
Now in the second form I want to have a button which allows users to disable all the styles and colors from the text and view it in plain text with "tahoma" font.
How can I do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In short, if you want to keep the styling intact but toggle it, perhaps the easiest way would be to create an override/reset css class declaration, and add/remove the class to the parent element on toggle button click. For instance, in a general way:

```
.noStyle, .noStyle *, .noStyle *[style]{
    font-family:Tahoma !important;
    font-size:14px !important;
    color:#000000 !important;
    ...etc
}
```